# How do I approach this proof to show that P (T, K) is non-decreasing function of T without making any model assumption

Tags: finance

Let P (T, K) be the price of a Put option with maturity T and strike K, and assume
that the interest rate is zero, i.e., r = 0. By no-arbitrage pricing rule, show that
P (T, K) is non-decreasing function of T without making any model assumption, i.e.,
show that for any K > 0,
P (T1, K) ≤ P (T2, K), ∀ 0 < T1 < T2,
in any model that does not have arbitrage

Comment: You should ask this in the finance forum or an economics forum, not here. Either that or define all the non-mathematical jargon you are tossing around like confetti, particularly the "no-arbitrage pricing rule". Also, you should explain what you've tried and where you are running into trouble.

Answer (score 0):

One possible way to go about this question, is to prove the following Lemma

**Lemma**

If $X_t$ is a martingale, $K < \infty$ a real constant, $0 < T_1 < T_2$ then

$$
\mathbb{E}[(K - X_{T_2})^{\text{+}}|\mathcal{F}_0] \ge \mathbb{E}[(K - X_{T_1})^{\text{+}}|\mathcal{F}_0]
$$

We can argue the proof like this:

$$
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
P(T_2, K) &= \mathbb{E}[(K - X_{T_2})^{\text{+}}|\mathcal{F}_0] \\
&= \mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}[(K - X_{T_2})^{\text{+}}|\mathcal{F}_1] \;| \mathcal{F}_0] \\
&\ge \mathbb{E}[(\mathbb{E}[(K - X_{T_2}|\mathcal{F}_1])^{\text{+}} \;| \mathcal{F}_0] \\
&= \mathbb{E}[(K - X_{T_1})^{\text{+}}|\mathcal{F}_0] = P(T_1, K)
\end{split}
\end{equation}
$$

where we used the tower property of the conditional expectation, Jensen inequality on the positive part function (which is convex) and the martingality of $X_t$.

There is also another possible solution, which is to emply the usual strategy *"buy low, sell high"* and look at the PnL at eah date, but I thought this derivation is a bit more elegant in my opinion.

Please note that this proof does not require a model and the No-Arbitrage condition is respected since the conditional expectation of the discounted payoff is the (fair) no arbitrage price of a put option (here since $r = 0$ you don't really see the discount, but it should be there)